# Cannot convert type System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<> to bool

Tags: c#, linq, collections

I'm trying to code this in an if condition:

```
if (submitAnswersResponseRootObject.Response.SubmitAnswersResult.Prompts.prompt.Where(p=>p.code == 7101))
```

but I'm getting error:

> Cannot implicitly convert type
>   System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<> to bool

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: use this `if (submitAnswersResponseRootObject.Response.SubmitAnswersResult.Prompts.prompt.Where(p=>p.code == 7101)).Any()`

Comment: Exactly as the error says. You are using the method `Where` which returns an `IEnumerable` and trying to use it as a condition for an if clause, which requires a `bool`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Maybe `Any` instead of `Where` that returns other collection (filtered)?

```
if (submitAnswersResponseRootObject.Response.SubmitAnswersResult.Prompts.prompt.Any(p=>p.code == 7101))
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe like this:

```
  if(submitAnswersResponseRootObject.Response.SubmitAnswersResult.Prompts.
  prompt.Where(p=>p.code == 7101).Any())
```